# PCB Screen Printing Problem

Tags: screen-printing

I exposed the board under the sun at 2 pm for 12 min, it got slightly overexposed I think as washing the not exposed part was a bit struggling.

But when I started to print through it for the first try some part of the layout didn't print well. So I thought the ink might a little thick for it so I made it a little thin with thinner, but after that the ink was flowing through it, made the whole board a mess.

I am using a oil based plastic paint.

Where am I going wrong?

Here's a picture of the board on the second try.

[image]

Here's the picture of the screen

[image]

Comment: As fascinating as I find this subject (it's many years since I messed with PCBs), the question really has nothing to do with the topic of GD.SE. You're much more likely to get an answer on a hobbyist forum than here.